# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 617: invalid start byte

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, utf-8, decode

```
File "d:\visual studio\python\sub.py", line 3, in <module>
    command_output = subprocess.run(["netsh", "wlan", "show", "profile"], capture_output = True).stdout.decode()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 617: invalid start byte
```

this runs without decode() but leaves out \r and \n
decode() throws unicode error does anyone know abt this?

Comment: The most obvious would be that the subprocess output doesn't use utf-8 encoding at all, and you're not telling Python which encoding it _does_ use, so Python's going "k, I'll assume it's utf-8" and so you get an error. But it also sounds like an XY problem here: you're running a single-line shell script, so you probably want `shell=True` in addition to capturing the output as per https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments